# What is the difference between 'aws-s3' and 'fog' gems?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, rubygems, refinerycms, fog

As in the subject: Do they compete, overlap or complement each other?

Thanks,

Petros

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They compete.
fog is more recent and still updated, whereas aws-s3 was not updated for months.

My advice : use fog.

Comment: Does fog allow for secure files on s3?

Comment: **aws-sdk** is official Ruby gem, under constantly maintenance

Answer (score 5):

Fog is a gem that provides a standard interface to amazon s3 and a lot of other cloud providers. To get an idea:

```
$ ls .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/fog-0.9.0/lib/fog/providers
aws.rb              ecloud.rb           new_servers.rb      virtual_box.rb
bluebox.rb          go_grid.rb          ninefold.rb         voxel.rb
brightbox.rb        google.rb           rackspace.rb        zerigo.rb
dnsimple.rb         linode.rb           slicehost.rb
dnsmadeeasy.rb      local.rb            storm_on_demand.rb
```

The standard interface should make it easier to switch providers later.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon just released the official [AWS SDK for Ruby](https://aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/) a couple of days ago. Documentation is here: http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/